# How to calculate the distance between an array and a matrix

Tags: r, distance

Consider a matrix A and an array b. I would like to calculate the distance between b and each row of A. For instance consider the following data:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15), 3, 5, byrow=TRUE)
b <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I would expect as output some array of the form:

```
distance_array = c(0, 11.18, 22.36)
```

where the value 11.18 comes from the euclidean distance between `a[2,]` and `b`:

```
sqrt(sum((a[2,]-b)^2))
```

This seems pretty basic but so far all R functions I have found allow to compute distance matrices between all the pairs of rows of a matrix, but not this array-matrix calculation.

Comment: How do you get 11.18 and 22.36?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend putting the rows a A in list instead of a matrix as it might allow for faster processing time. But here's how I would do it with respect to your example

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15), 3, 5, byrow=TRUE)

b <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

apply(A,1,function(x)sqrt(sum((x-b)^2)))
```